# Accumulating data based on two criteria

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am trying to write a VB.NET program that reads data from a file and does a count for each column as shown in the format below and also writes to an output file.

I am able to do the count but I am unable to write the output per restaurant and day.

From what I have, I can only write the total sum from the array index.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Dim IntSubjectArray(23) As String

OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
strInputPath = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
FileOpen(IntInputFileName, strInputPath, OpenMode.Input)
Do While Not EOF(IntInputFileName)
    Dim StrReadLine As String = LineInput(IntInputFileName)
    Dim StrSplitRecord() As String = Split(StrReadLine, ",")
    IntRestaurant = StrSplitRecord(0)
    IntDay = StrSplitRecord(1)
    Meal1 = StrSplitRecord(2)
    Meal2 = StrSplitRecord(3)
    Meal3 = StrSplitRecord(4)
    If SaveDay <> IntDay Then
        IntMealArray(meal1) += 1
        IntMealArray(meal2) += 1
        IntMealArray(meal3) += 1
        SaveDay = IntDay
        SaveDay = 0
    End If
    savetown = IntExamTown
Loop
Call WriteOutputArray()
FileClose(IntInputFileName)
MessageBox.Show("File written to specified location")
```

```
Public Sub WriteOutputArray()
    IntOutputFileName = FreeFile()
    For Each Array As String In IntMealArray
        FileOpen(IntOutputFileName, "C:\Users\ireport\foodCount.txt", OpenMode.Append)
        WriteLine(IntOutputFileName, IntMealArray(Array))
        FileClose(IntOutputFileName)
    Next
End Sub
```

File format is

```
001,1,5,6,21
001,1,5,6,21
001,1,5,6,21
001,1,10,12,18
001,2,5,6,19
001,2,8,9,19
001,2,6,19,21
001,2,5,6,21
001,3,7,12,18
001,3,8,12,19
001,3,7,12,18
040,4,7,12,18
040,4,7,12,18
040,4,7,12,18
040,4,9,12,19
```

Key:
The format is 001 is restaurant 1, then day 1, then foods eaten by a particular customer (there are to 23 different kinds of food), with each kind of meal represented by a code 1 to 23 as in the file.

Expected output is count of food eaten in each resturant in each day by a customer e.g.:

```
Rest day Rice   Beans Yam  Meat  Snack coke Burger Meal8 Meal9  Meal10  M11  M12
001   1    0     0     0    0     3      3     0     0     0      1      0    1
001   2    0     0     0    0     2      3     0     1     1      0      0    0
001   3    0     0     0    0     0      0     2     1     0      0      0    3
040   4    0     0     0    0     0      0     3     0     1      0      0    4
```

Comment: Could you adjust your example so that the expected output is the actual expected output from the file data shown? Then we can confirm our code works. And maybe give us the correlation between food code and food name for the ones shown.

Comment: Hello Olivier, Thanks for your swift response. Each meal has a code from 1 to 23. The expected output for my example is:

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: Hello Oliver, i have edited the expected output of my post. Each Meal is represented by a code(num) from 1-23. The idea is to know the total number of each meal consumed in a particular resturant. Like; At restuarant 001, Meal 5 was consumed 3 times in day 1

Comment: @Mary I am not experiencing any runtime error.

Comment: You will. Option Strict should be on for 99.99% of your code.

Comment: Each entry in your input file has 3 articles. What happens if someone consumes 2 or 4 things? Does the input file have a varying number of entries per line? The expected output still does not match the input file. E.g. restaurant 001 day 1: article no. 5 appears 3 times. I don't see this number in your expected output.

Comment: @Olivier Jacot, that was an oversight as I did it manually. article 5 actually appears 3times. morealso, according to the input file format, you can't consume more than 3 things

Comment: How does the input look if there are less than 3 things?

Comment: `001,1,5,,` or `001,1,5,0,0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get your data into some format which will make it easier to see in the code which part is which. An easy way to do that is create a Class with properties which have meaningful names.

Then you can group the data by restaurant, and for each restaurant you can group the data for each date.

As the output is in columns of the widths of the names of the foods, you need to take those names into account when formatting the output.

For simplicity, I created a console app instead of a Windows Forms app. Also, I would split it up into more methods if I was doing this for more than a proof-of-concept.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Module Module1

    Dim Foods As Dictionary(Of String, String)

    Class Datum
        Property Restaurant As String
        Property Day As Integer
        Property FoodCodes As List(Of String)

        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            ' Useful for debugging.
            Return $"{Restaurant} {Day} " & String.Join(",", FoodCodes)
        End Function

    End Class

    Sub LoadFoods()
        ' Generate some food names. The first food name has a code of "1".
        Foods = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
        Dim names = {"Rice", "Beans", "Banana", "Meat", "Snacks", "Potato", "Spinach",
            "Fish", "Aubergine", "Peas", "Egg", "Chicken", "Cheese", "Onion",
            "Carrots", "Brocolli", "Asparagus", "Garlic", "Cabbage", "Coconut", "Yam",
            "Naan", "Lentils"}

        For i = 1 To names.Count
            Foods.Add(i.ToString(), names(i - 1))
        Next

    End Sub

    Sub Main()
        LoadFoods()

        Dim src = "C:\temp\FoodRecords.txt"
        Dim dest = "C:\temp\meals.txt"

        Dim data As New List(Of Datum)

        For Each line In File.ReadLines(src)
            Dim parts = line.Split({","c})
            If parts.Count = 5 Then
                Dim d As New Datum With {.Restaurant = parts(0),
                                         .Day = Integer.Parse(parts(1)),
                                         .FoodCodes = parts.Skip(2).OrderBy(Function(s) s).ToList()}
                data.Add(d)

            End If
        Next

        ' Prepare information on the widths of the columns to be output...
        Dim colWidths As New List(Of Integer)
        colWidths.Add(-("Restaurant".Length))
        colWidths.Add(-("Day".Length))

        For Each food In Foods
            colWidths.Add(food.Value.Length)
        Next

        ' Group the data by restaurant...
        Dim restaurantData = From d In data
                             Group By RestCode = d.Restaurant
                             Into RestData = Group


        Using sw As New StreamWriter(dest)
            sw.Write("Restaurant Day ")
            sw.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", Foods.Select(Function(f) f.Value)))

            For Each x In restaurantData
                'Console.WriteLine(x.RestCode & " " & String.Join(",", x.RestData))

                ' Get each day of data for this restaurant
                Dim restaurantDay = From y In x.RestData
                                    Group By Day = y.Day
                                    Into DayData = Group


                For Each rd In restaurantDay

                    ' Count the occurrences of food codes for this day...
                    Dim dayFoodCounts As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

                    For Each fd In rd.DayData
                        For Each fc In fd.FoodCodes
                            If dayFoodCounts.ContainsKey(fc) Then
                                dayFoodCounts(fc) += 1
                            Else
                                dayFoodCounts.Add(fc, 1)
                            End If
                        Next

                    Next

                    ' Generate the first two columns
                    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
                    Dim fmt = "{0," & colWidths(0) & "}"
                    sb.AppendFormat(fmt, x.RestCode)
                    sb.Append(" ")
                    fmt = "{0," & colWidths(1) & "}"
                    sb.AppendFormat(fmt, rd.Day)
                    sb.Append(" ")

                    ' Generate the columns with food consumption counts
                    Dim n = 0
                    For Each kvp In Foods
                        If dayFoodCounts.ContainsKey(kvp.Key) Then
                            sb.Append(String.Format("{0," & colWidths(n + 2) & "}", dayFoodCounts(kvp.Key)) & " ")
                        Else
                            ' no count for this food item, so fill it with spaces
                            sb.Append(New String(" "c, colWidths(n + 2) + 1))
                        End If

                        n += 1
                    Next

                    sw.WriteLine(sb.ToString())

                Next

            Next

        End Using

        Console.WriteLine("Done.")
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Given the sample data from the question, the above code generates a file with this content:

```
Restaurant Day Rice Beans Banana Meat Snacks Potato Spinach Fish Aubergine Peas Egg Chicken Cheese Onion Carrots Brocolli Asparagus Garlic Cabbage Coconut Yam Naan Lentils
001        1                               3      3                           1           1                                              1                   3              
001        2                               2      3            1         1                                                                       3           2              
001        3                                              2    1                          3                                              2       1                          
040        4                                              3              1                4                                              3       1
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Your code works fine for the problem i am trying to solve. However, I'm more conversant with windows forms app. Is there no way this can be done using windows forms App?

Comment: @Cyril1 Yes: from Main(), move `LoadFoods()` to the Form_Load handler. Move the rest of the code in Main() to a new method. Set `src` and `dest` any way you like (e.g. with an OpenFileDialog). Change `Console.WriteLine("Done.")` to `MessageBox.Show("File written to specified location.")`. Delete the line `Console.ReadLine()`. Put the `Imports` statements at the top of the code (if you haven't got them already). Put the `Dim Foods....` line after your `Public Class YourFormName` line. Put the `Class Datum` and the `LoadFoods()` method just after that. Press F5 and see if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

(In my previous solution I had wrongly assumed that the numbers are counts and each column represents an article, which was not the case. Here my new solution.)

I would separate reading the file from writing the table. To be able to represent the content of the file easily, let's create a class to represent food.

```
Public Class Food
    Public Property Restaurant As String
    Public Property Day As Integer
    Public Property ArticleNo As Integer
    Public Property Quantity As Integer
End Class
```

The `Quantity` property is not strictly necessary, since it will always be 1. But it seems logical to have it in case the file format evolves in future.

Now we can read the file like this

```
Public Function ReadFoodFile(inputPath As String) As List(Of Food)
    Dim foodList = New List(Of Food)
    For Each line As String In File.ReadLines(inputPath)
        Dim parts As String() = line.Split(",")
        If parts.Length > 2 Then 'Make sure we don't try to read an empty line,
            '                     e.g.at the end of the file.
            Dim dayNo As Integer = CInt(parts(1))
            For i = 2 To parts.Length - 1
                Dim articleNo As Integer
                If Int32.TryParse(parts(i), articleNo) AndAlso articleNo <> 0 Then
                    Dim food = New Food()
                    food.Restaurant = parts(0)
                    food.Day = dayNo
                    food.ArticleNo = articleNo
                    food.Quantity = 1
                    foodList.Add(food)
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
    Return foodList
End Function
```

The function for reading the file has the input path as parameter and returns a list of food where each entry corresponds to one restaurant, one day and one food article.

This was the easy part. Writing the table is complicated as we must group by restaurants and days as well as by article for each row. Then we must be able to look up the article by its article number. We need a class representing an article:

```
Public Class Article
    Public Property ArticleNo As Integer
    Public Property Name As String

    Public Sub New(articleNo As Integer, name As String)
        Me.ArticleNo = articleNo
        Me.Name = name
    End Sub

    Private Shared _allArticles = New Article() {
        New Article(1, "Rice"), New Article(2, "Beans"), New Article(3, "Yam"), New Article(4, "Meat"),
        New Article(5, "Snack"), New Article(6, "Coke"), New Article(7, "Burger"), New Article(8, "Meal8"),
        New Article(9, "Meal9"), New Article(10, "Meal10"), New Article(11, "M11"), New Article(12, "M12"),
        New Article(13, "M13"), New Article(14, "M14"), New Article(15, "M15"), New Article(16, "M16"),
        New Article(17, "M17"), New Article(18, "M18"), New Article(19, "M19"), New Article(20, "M20"),
        New Article(21, "M21"), New Article(22, "M22"), New Article(23, "M23")
    }

    Shared ReadOnly Property AllArticles() As Article()
        Get
            Return _allArticles
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Besides article no. and name, it contains a shared property returning a list of articles. In a real-life application, the list of articles should probably be read from a file or a database instead of being hard-coded.

Now, we can formulate the Sub writing the table. It makes heavy use of LINQ and uses the new `ValueTuple` type available since VB/VS 2017.

```
Public Sub WriteFoodTable(outputPath As String, foods As IEnumerable(Of Food))
    Const ColumnSize = 8

    'Create an IEnumerable(Of (Restaurant As String,
    '                          Day As Integer,
    '                          Articles As Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer))
    '                         )
    '                     )
    ' where the dictionary stores article quantities using the article no. as key.
    Dim groupedFood = From food In foods
                      Group By food.Restaurant, food.Day Into g1 = Group
                      Select (
                          Restaurant:=Restaurant, Day:=Day,
                          Articles:=
                            (From x In g1
                             Group By x.ArticleNo Into g2 = Group
                             Select (ArticleNo:=ArticleNo,
                                     Quantity:=g2.Sum(Function(f) f.Quantity))
                            ).ToDictionary(Function(a) a.ArticleNo, Function(a) a.Quantity)
                      )

    Using writer As New StreamWriter(outputPath)
        ' Write header
        writer.Write("Rest  Day")
        For Each art In Article.AllArticles
            writer.Write(art.Name.PadLeft(ColumnSize))
        Next
        writer.WriteLine()

        ' Write rows
        For Each row In groupedFood
            writer.Write(row.Restaurant.PadRight(5))
            writer.Write(row.Day.ToString().PadLeft(4))
            For Each art In Article.AllArticles
                Dim quantity As Integer
                row.Articles.TryGetValue(art.ArticleNo, quantity) ' yields 0 if not found.
                writer.Write(quantity.ToString().PadLeft(ColumnSize))
            Next
            writer.WriteLine()
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

Putting things together

```
Dim foods As List(Of Food) = ReadFoodFile(inputPath)
WriteFoodTable(outputPath, foods)
```

See also:

- [Tuples (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/tuples)
- [LINQ in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/linq/)

Comment: I've reworked my solution according to your comments and new information.

Comment: Hello @Olivier Jacot-Descombes, thanks for your effort. But I would like to know if you tested your solution. I'm trying it out but I encounter a lot of error

Comment: Yes, I have tested this solution. It works and produces the desired result file. Can it be that the real input files don't look exactly as you have shown? You also might have to add some `Imports` at the top of your code.

Comment: The input file looks exactly as shown. I also import system.io and system.text. yet it keeps flagging error. maybe you omitted some declarations? I'll keep working on it though. I'll update you

Comment: I can't tell you without seeing the error messages.